# VSCode create profile from extensions-dir

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm used to starting VSCode like `code . --extensions-dir "D:\vscode\XXX\exts" --user-data-dir "D:\vscode\XXX\data"`. Today, I took notice of the command line switch `--profile` and the possibility to create profiles from existing setups.
I created a new profile from the cog icon and checked all boxes in the dialog but choose to copy nothing from the dropdown. Eventually, I found myself in a new but empty profile.

In a second try I created another profile. I, again, checked all boxes but selected to copy from `Standard` in the dropdown. I got the impression the settings were copied from the "profile" that comes up, when code is started without providing an individual extensions dir and not from extensions-dir and user-data-dir I provided on the command line.

How do I create a profile from using the data in these directories?

Comment: it's not clear to me what you actually want. please try to state it more clearly